# Find object keys with empty string values

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I'm trying to get the keys named `key2` which has the value `""` from a JSON file as below through `jq`.

I'm using `jq` in `Windows PowerShell`. Can someone please help me ?

```
{
    "Key": "value",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": ""
}
```

Comment: Your title says "have null", your text says "have an empty string". Which one is it?

Comment: one which has empty string

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_entries`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries(f)) to get an array of key-value-pairs, then iterate it with [`.[]`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) it and [`select`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) the pairs with an empty value, and finally extract the [`.key`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar) from the pair:

```
to_entries[] | select(.value=="") | .key
```

Output:

```
"key2"
```

To run with Windows PowerShell, you should be able to quote the whole expression with single quotes:

```
jq 'to_entries[] | select(.value=="") | .key'
```

At least that's what [the documentation of PowerShell 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#including-quote-characters-in-a-string) suggests.

If that does not work either, you can store your jq program in a file (e.g. `find-keys.jq` with content `to_entries[] | select(.value=="") | .key`) and then load it with `jq -f find-keys.jq`

Comment: thanks for the reply knittl. I'm having issues executing the query in Windows due to the Quotes issue.

I get below error message.

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START, expecting ';' or ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
to_entries | select(.value==""")
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: @NKRSHNA did you quote the program? See the updated answer with possible workarounds

Comment: yes I quoted the program but still seeing the error

$Data | jq -r 'to_entries | select(.value==") | .key'   
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
to_entries | select(.value==)
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: @NKRSHNA you have `.value=="` which is an unterminated string. It must be `.value==""` (sorry, it looks like this got messed up in the second code snippet in my answer. The first snippet had the correct version. It is fixed now)

Comment: I tried using both the options but still have the same issue.

Comment: @NKRSHNA did you try the workaround with `jq -f` and providing a file with the first code block as content? It's not possible to get shell quoting issues that way, because no shell is involved. Check your file for any typos (missing quotes, extra quotes, missing/extra parentheses/brackets, …)